# How to check all Items in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, arraylist, android-listview

I read the text messages from the SQLite database, which I then place in an Array List which is displayed to the user in a `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`

This is how I currently check individual Items in the list.(This code is within my onclick)

```
 final  TextMessagesList backupSms = new TextMessagesList(txtList);
                    String selected = "";
                    int cntChoice =  smsListView.getCount();
                    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = smsListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                        if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                            selected += smsListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";

                        }
                    }
Toast.makeText(Backup.this,selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I am able to select individual check-box's and then toast what has been selected. 
 My question is how can I check/ all items when I check the first item in the list

Can anyone please help me work out what I need to do next?

Thank you in advance for your help it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Emanuel's answer should make the checkboxes checked, there is no certainty that the ListView will also know about which items are checked and which aren't. To be safe, I would use [`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount%28%29) and [`setItemChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) instead:

```
for (int x = 0; x < smsListView.getCount(); x++) {
    smsListView.setItemChecked (x, true);
}
```

To uncheck everything, follow the same template, but replace the `true` with `false`.

Comment: Hey @A-C I tried your way and I got it to work, just wanted to say thank you, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question together with your code leave some room for interpretation.
From my interpretation that would be the likely answer to the question:

```
int count = smsListView.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    CheckedTextView v = (CheckedTextView) smsListView.getChildAt(i);
    v.setChecked(true);
}
```

If that's not what you need, then please elaborate on the question.

Comment: Why not use [`setItemChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean)) instead?

Comment: Hi Emanuel, I believe your my code does leave some room for interpretation I did try your way but it doesn't seem to select everything when the item is clicked.                                                  What I'm trying to do is when I check the first checkbox I want all the boxes to be checked.